# Как перевести текст в html разметке (с ру на укр), при этом сохранив целостность разметки?

Tags: html, перевод

Столкнулся с проблемой перевода текста на другой язык, при этом сохранив целостность всей html разметки.

Перепробовал такие метода как:

1. Перевести страницу сайта и скопировать текст, но код уж очень грязный и слетают ссылки проставленные в словах.
2. Вставить в ячейку Googledocs и функцией =GOOGLETRANSLATE(). Опять же ломается код, но меньше. Ручная работа остаётся. И через EXCEL с функцией, тоже не ахти.
3. Пробовал перевод частями, но это долго, объём кол-ва текстов большой.
4. Так же пересмотрел кучу плагинов-переводчиков для браузера и скриптов авто-перевода. Тоже все долго и напряжно.

Суть такова что хочется взять полностью текст с html версткой (без картинок) и без каких либо правок/убирания пробелов/чисткой кода/танцев с частью текста и перевести на другой язык.

Извиняюсь сразу, возможно за некорректный вопрос..

Пример кода ДО и ПОСЛЕ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вам это динамически или статически? если статически - прогоните через переводчик гугл (например, https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&pto=aue&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=ru&sp=nmt4&tl=uk&u=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/&usg=ALkJrhinKL1w1Xto1Qp4cKGQWxKhnfH1hg) и из результата заберите html код

Comment: Статически я так понимаю. @Zhihar, дело в том что так и пробовал, забирал html код после перевода текста, но туда попадают <font style ......></font>, которых в обычной верстке текста нету.

Comment: Используйте профессиональный инструмент для перевода. Transifex, Crowdin, Smartcat. Они умеют разделять текст и теги, и там есть ещё много полезных фич для перводчиков. Но инструменты платные.